# Determines the first integer that is evenly divisible by all other integers in a list of integers

Tags: python

```
def divisible(a):

    d = 0
    n = len(a)
    i = 0
    p = 0
    while d == 0 and p < n and i < n:
        if a[i] % a[p] != 0:
            i = i + 1
            p = 0
        else:
            p = p + 1

    return d

a = [12, 4, 6]
r = divisible(a)
print(r)
```

Can anyone help me plsease? it is python 3.0 +. I can't solve this question, I don't know where I can put d into the function. like let d = a[i] if a[i] can evenly divisible by all other integers. The answer is 12 for this question, can anyone imporve my code plsease? Thank you!!

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `gcd()` function? That would be much faster for many or large numbers in your list.

Comment: I am not allowed to use the gcd() function, I forgot to say. thank you

Comment: Then are you looking for a simple answer (similar to yours) or an efficient answer (which would code a simple `lcm()` and `gcd()` function: they are not difficult)?

Comment: This is sort of cheap, but if you know that there is such an integer, it is the one with a larger absolute value between max(a) and min(a). Except for maybe a special case like 0 in a. I did not include this as an answer because it's more important that you actually compute it to verify the input.

Comment: I am looking for sample answer, just similar what  I did. Thank you

Comment: Alrighty, I filled in the details in an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

A short solution would be

```
def divisible(a):
    for i in a:
        if all(i%j==0 for j in a):
            return i
    return None
```

or a bit longer

```
def divisible(a):
    for i in a:
        found=True
        for j in a:
            if i%j: # everything that is not 0 is true
                found=False
                break
        if found:
            return i
    return None
```

Comment: I can't use the all(), do you have any other ways to make sure  all i%j==0? Thank you.

Comment: added longer solution wihout `all`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the least common multiple algorithm, in python3 you could code it like this:

```
from fractions import gcd
from functools import reduce


def lcm(*args):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a * b // gcd(a, b), args)

print lcm(4, 6, 12)
```

But it seems you can't use any functions nor python builtin operators in your algorithm because educational purposes. Then one possible simple solution could just be like this:

```
def divisible(input_list):
    result = None

    if 0 in input_list:
        return result

    for i in input_list:
        ok = True
        for j in input_list:
            if i!=j and i % j != 0:
                ok = False
                break

        if ok:
            return i

    return result
```

Comment: @xgord: you are confusing gcd and lcm. The lcm of 10 and 4 is 20, while the gcd of 10 and 4 is 2. This code does find the lcm, but it uses the gcd() function that the OP does not want. The OP added that requirement after this answer was posted, so don't punish BPL for the OP's lack of completeness. The OP also wants the lcm to be an item of the list, but he stated that badly.

Answer (score 0):

I have expended on my previous comment. We don't need to actually compute any multiples, since we expect it to already be in the list. The trick is just to take the max (or min, if negative numbers are allowed), and then validate.

But first, figure out how you are going to handle 0. It is divisible by all other integers, and cannot itself divide any integer, so I just return 0 in this example.

Also decide what you will do if you determine there is no correct answer. I returned None, but an exception may be more appropriate depending on the application.

```
def divisible(input_list):
    # what to do with zero?
    if 0 in input_list:
        return 0
    # get largest magnitude
    candidate = max(map(abs, input_list))
    # validate
    if all([0 == candidate % x for x in input_list]):
        return candidate
    else:
        # handle the case where there is no valid answer
        return None

print divisible([12, 4, 6])
print divisible([-12, 4, 6, -3])
print divisible([12, 5, 7])
print divisible([12, 0, 4])
```

This has some similarity to janbrohl's answer, but that is an O(n**2) solution, checking every number against every other number. But we know the number we want will be the largest (in magnitude).

Proof by contradiction: Take two positive numbers [a, b] where a < b, and suppose that a is evenly divisible by b. But then a % b == 0.  Since a < b, we know that a % b is a.  Therefore a=0 or a=nb (for some n).  But a < b, therefore a==0.  (expand to signed integers on your own. The sign is largely irrelevant for determining divisibility.)

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use all(), are there any other ways to do the same thing?

Comment: You ... what? Can't use all? Class assignment? Can you use max()? If so, then I feel I have pointed you in the right direction, and saying any more is more harmful in the long run.

Comment: its a final exam practice question. I am going to take the exam after 4 hrs. thank you tho!!

Comment: Reviewing your question in light of that information, what you need to know is that any loop must terminate. Since this is python, we do "for x in somelist:" and we know that x will advance through each item in the list. You used an index, so it should be "for i in range(len(somelist)):", but since you had two loops, what you need is two loops (both of which must advance through each item independently) where one loop is completely inside the other.

Comment: And the point of my answer here was that iterating through two nexted loops is horribly slow when you don't need to compare each item to each other item. You know the answer will be the biggest, so just find that in one loop. Then do your other loop.

Comment: candidate = max(input_list, key=lambda x: abs(x)) also works. Now I'm just having fun with it. :)

Comment: I am going to cry now -_-. really can't do this question, I don't know why, my brain is not working now

Comment: When it seems complicated, just break it down into simpler functions. Test and fix those. That's how everyone does complicated stuff, and it's the right way.